# Milhões de usuários simultâneamente no Android

Tags: android

vejo que só tem fera nessa página,e sou novo no desenvolvimento no mobile,então gostaria de saber como algumas coisas funcionam,supondo que eu crie um APP,e ele vai ter um banco de dados,os milhões de usúarios irão acessar essas informações usando um servidor,webservices,então gostaria de entender como funciona essa estrutura,pra poder estudar á fundo!
desde já o meu muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom Luiz,

O Android em si possuí uma banco de dados que fica no próprio dispositivo, guardando assim os dados locais da sua aplicação.

Se você desejar guardar estas informações, tratá-las ou interagir com essas informações, será necessário configurar um servidor, nele você configura um banco de dados central para todos os seus usuários e configura um Webservice funcionando em REST ou SOAP para receber e enviar as informações para seus usuários.

Bom estudo :)

Comment: muito bom amigo,as coisas no inicio são bem confusas,trabalho de porteiro em um condominio,e tenho um tempo disponivel lá pra estudar,e estudar em casa também quero muito me tornar um desenvolvedor mobile,e minha dúvida era essa,esse banco de dados interno eu já até consigo fazer algumas coisinhas,mais dai fiquei pensando como uma app mais alto nível funcionaria,como facebook por exemplo,onde ocorre milhões de acesso simultâneos,desde já o meu muito obrigado,ouvi falar de um site que você consegue uma pessoa experiente para ir te auxiliando,já ouviu falar sr Lucas?

Comment: Não conheço, acho legal sua iniciativa, nessa área 90% do que é aprendido é através  de auto didatismo mesmo, recomendo esse site: https://www.udacity.com/account/auth#!/signin?next=https%3A%2F%2Fclassroom.udacity.com%2Fcourses%2Fud837&enroll=ud837 ele tem um curso excelente gratuíto no formato de vídeo aula, o site e todo o conteúdo é em inglês, porém nesse curso 90% dos vídeos possuem legendas em português, mas de qualquer forma, o inglês tem que ser aprendido pra trabalhar nessa área

Comment: vlw lucas obrigado pela dica,vou seguir sua recomendação!